# Wrong units in QGIS distance matrix

Tags: qgis, distance, error

I am trying to teach myself QGIS. I have been following the following notes: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html
While trying to reproduce the results from the link above, I have found that my output units are terribly wrong. In the example above the distances are between 0 and 1; however, my results seem to be in meters as they are considerably larger than those on the tutorial (they are all larger than 1000). I am using QGIS 3.4 on a Mac and I have checked that the CRS that I am using is the same as the one in the example. Any ideas regarding what could be wrong and how to fix it? Are you aware of another tutorial on the distance matrix?

Comment: What input data are you using? Have you checked the coordinate system of this data? Coupled with that what is the CRS you are using in the main map?

Comment: I am using EPSG:4326, both of the datasets are on the same CRS.

Comment: is the QGIS project also in the same CRS? you can check that in the bottom right corner of the QGIS window.  I suspect the project CRS is a projected one, or at least not EPSG:4326.

Comment: Check under Project properties > General > Measurements > Unit for distance measurement. Ensure this is on degrees not meters.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, unfortunately, any of the solutions have worked. I retried it on a Windows computer and got the same results.